is the interrupt handler supposed to jump back to the faulty instruction once done?
I am writing a small OS on ARM v7. I emulate a raspberry PI on qemu. I have written an interrupt vector table with handlers and am unsure whether the handler is supposed to jump back to the faulty instruction once finished. It might look daunting but its not a lot to understand. I just subtract 4 or 8 bytes from the link register and save it along with r0-r12 on the stack so that I can pass a pointer to the registers as parameter into C handler functions.
Now, once I jump back am I supposed to jump to the interrupt cause or one after? thanks!
undefined_instruction:
    sub lr, #4
    stmfd sp!, {r0-r12,lr}
    mov r0, sp
    bl undefined_instruction_C
    LDMIA sp!, {r0-r12,pc}^

software_interrupt:
    sub lr, #4
    stmfd sp!, {r0-r12,lr}
    mov r0, sp
    bl software_interrupt_C
    LDMIA sp!, {r0-r12,pc}^


not_used:
    mov r0,r0

irq:
    sub lr, #8
    stmfd sp!, {r0-r12,lr}
    mov r0, sp
    bl irq_C
    LDMIA sp!, {r0-r12,pc}^

fiq:
    sub lr, #4
    stmfd sp!, {r0-r12,lr}
    mov r0, sp
    bl fiq_C
    LDMIA sp!, {r0-r12,pc}^

reset:
    mov r0,r0

prefetch_abort:
    sub lr, #4
    stmfd sp!, {r0-r12,lr}
    mov r0, sp
    bl prefetch_abort_C
    LDMIA sp!, {r0-r12,pc}^

data_abort:
    sub lr, #8
    stmfd sp!, {r0-r12,lr}
    mov r0, sp
    bl data_abort_C
    LDMIA sp!, {r0-r12,pc}^


.global _INIT_IVT
_INIT_IVT:
    ldr r0, =_ivt
    mcr p15, 0, r0, c12, c0, 0  
    bx lr

    
.global _ivt
.balign 64
_ivt:
    b reset
    ldr pc, _undefined_instruction
    ldr pc, _software_interrupt
    ldr pc, _prefetch_abort
    ldr pc, _data_abort
    ldr pc, _not_used
    ldr pc, _irq
    ldr pc, _fiq
_undefined_instruction: .word undefined_instruction
_software_interrupt: .word software_interrupt
_prefetch_abort: .word prefetch_abort
_data_abort: .word data_abort
_not_used: .word not_used
_irq: .word irq
_fiq: .word fiq


Interrupts are triggered by external events. Exceptions (faults and traps) are triggered by instructions. If you are handling fault that has been corrected, you can restart the instruction that caused the fault.
If you are handling an interrupt, you could go back to the process's instruction stream or you could call the scheduler and pick the process to execute.

Some other cases: if the fault can't be corrected (e.g. illegal instruction, process has touched a page that isn't merely swapped out but actually not mapped) then you kill the process, or maybe return to its error handler if it has one.  If you've emulated the faulted instruction (e.g. a floating-point math instruction on a machine that lacks the hardware), then return to the following instruction.
